# Parsing related group of lines in a text file using python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have this file containing this text:

```
$ more audit.log
2018-01-31 15:34:08 GMT:10.34.160.60(63788):agent3@pem:[31884]00000:LOG:  statement: DROP TABLE tmp_zombies
2018-01-31 15:58:52 GMT:127.0.0.1(45050):agent1@pem:[13182]00000:LOG:  statement: CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_zombies(jagpid int4)
2018-01-31 15:58:52 GMT:127.0.0.1(45050):agent1@pem:[13182]00000:LOG:  statement: DROP TABLE tmp_zombies
2018-01-31 16:24:00 GMT:10.34.160.55(57199):agent8@pem:[27888]00000:LOG:  statement: CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_zombies(jagpid int4)
2018-01-31 16:24:00 GMT:10.34.160.55(57199):agent8@pem:[27888]00000:LOG:  statement: DROP TABLE tmp_zombies
2018-01-31 21:08:47 GMT:[local]:pgsql@p106:[26349]00000:LOG:  statement: create table global_pg_audit
        (
           rolename         text not null,
           stmt_timestamp   timestamp not null,
           source_ip        text,
           target_ip        text,
           dbname           text,
           pid              text,
           statement_type   text,
           statement        text
        );
2018-01-31 15:34:08 GMT:10.34.160.60(63788):agent3@pem:[31884]00000:LOG:  statement: DROP TABLE tmp_zombies
```

When I run this python code:

```
    import re
    fullpathname='./audit.log'
    regex_pattern=re.compile(r'^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(.*?)$',re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
    with open(fullpathname,'r') as f:
        log_entries = regex_pattern.findall(f.read())
    counter=0
    for entry in log_entries:
        print '%d=>['%(counter),entry,']'
        counter=counter+1
```

The output is as follows:

```
0=>[ ('2018-01-31 15:34:08', ' GMT:10.34.160.60(63788):agent3@pem:[31884]00000:LOG:  statement: DROP TABLE tmp_zombies') ]
1=>[ ('2018-01-31 15:58:52', ' GMT:127.0.0.1(45050):agent1@pem:[13182]00000:LOG:  statement: CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_zombies(jagpid int4)') ]
2=>[ ('2018-01-31 15:58:52', ' GMT:127.0.0.1(45050):agent1@pem:[13182]00000:LOG:  statement: DROP TABLE tmp_zombies') ]
3=>[ ('2018-01-31 16:24:00', ' GMT:10.34.160.55(57199):agent8@pem:[27888]00000:LOG:  statement: CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_zombies(jagpid int4)') ]
4=>[ ('2018-01-31 16:24:00', ' GMT:10.34.160.55(57199):agent8@pem:[27888]00000:LOG:  statement: DROP TABLE tmp_zombies') ]
5=>[ ('2018-01-31 21:08:47', ' GMT:[local]:pgsql@p106:[26349]00000:LOG:  statement: create table global_pg_audit ') ]
6=>[ ('2018-01-31 15:34:08', ' GMT:10.34.160.60(63788):agent3@pem:[31884]00000:LOG:  statement: DROP TABLE tmp_zombies') ]
7=>[ ('2018-01-31 15:58:52', ' GMT:127.0.0.1(45050):agent1@pem:[13182]00000:LOG:  statement: CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_zombies(jagpid int4)') ]
```

Notice that line 5 in the output, the code did not include the entire statement which should be:

```
    create table global_pg_audit
        (
           rolename         text not null,
           stmt_timestamp   timestamp not null,
           source_ip        text,
           target_ip        text,
           dbname           text,
           pid              text,
           statement_type   text,
           statement        text
        );
```

What is wrong with the code?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is anchored to the end of the line:

```
^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(.*?)$
```

Since you've enabled multi-line mode, `$` matches at a line break. That's why the match ends after `global_pg_audit`.

---

You want to match until the next line that starts with a date. You can use a lookahead to do this:

```
^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(.*?)(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}|\Z)
```

The alternation `|\Z` allows the regex to match the last line even though it's not followed by a date.

See also the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZhCj18/1).

Comment: Thank you.  Works very well.